# How to match a substring at the end of a string, and then delete only that substring?

Tags: regex, vba, replace, trim

I have a column of text in each cell, with the string `null` at the end of many of them. I'd like to parse through each cell in the column and remove *just* `null` from the cell if the cell's contents end with that string.

What I've written so far removes `null` from the end successfully if there is a space between it and the preceding word, but removes the *whole cell's* contents if there is no space between the preceding word and `null`.

```vba
Sub TruncateNulls()

    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\w*null\b"
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        strInput = ActiveCell.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = False
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            ActiveCell = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Example input data:

```
words
null
wordsnull
words null
nullwords
```

Desired output data:

```
words

words
words
nullwords
```

**How can I adjust this to only remove the ending `null`, irrespective of preceding characters?**

Alternatively, I'm open to using Excel's `Find` feature, or a specific wildcard/wildcard combination in the Search & Replace window, if either of those options work.

Comment: `If strInput Like "*null" Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Replace` with the pattern `\s*null$` to delete all the occurrences at the end of each cell. You should also consider loading the range in an array to improve the execution time.

```
Sub TruncateNulls()
    Dim rg As Range, data()

    ' select the range to the last row
    Set rg = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & rows.Count).end(xlUp))

    ' load the data in an array
    data = rg.value

    ' replace each value with a regex
    ArrayReplace data, pattern:="\s*null$", replacement:=Empty

    ' write the array back to the sheet
    rg.value = data
End Sub


Sub ArrayReplace(data(), pattern As String, replacement As String)
    Dim re As New RegExp, r As Long, c As Long

    re.Global = True
    re.MultiLine = False
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.pattern = pattern

    For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
            If VarType(data(r, c)) = vbString Then
                data(r, c) = re.Replace(data(r, c), replacement)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: All the answers work, and do so fairly quickly, but this appears to be the most efficient, which makes it the most useful for this and future endeavors.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer the current approach, you need to replace your pattern with

```
\s*null\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MuNvKz/1)

**Details**

- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces (replace `\s` with a space or `[^\S\r\n]` if you do not want to overflow across lines)
- `null` - a `null` substring
- `\s*` - 1 or more whitespaces (see the same note as above)
- `$`  - end of line (set `.Multiline` flag to *False* to match the end of string).

Comment: That site is very useful, thanks! Probably would have been able to tinker out a solution much easier had I known about it. On it, I'm finding `\snull$` and `\snull\b` seem to work equally as well.

Comment: @TylerH Just bear in mind that `\b` is a [*word boundary*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1539/word-boundary) and `$` is the [*end of string anchor*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1603/anchor-characters-dollar). They act differently. The `\b` after `null` requires the next char to be a non-letter, non-digit and non-`_` or end of string. `$` only requires the end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than regex in this case is simply checking the 4 last characters with the `Right()` function. Your code could be reduced to

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    strInput = ActiveCell.Value
    If Right(strInput, 4) = "null" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = Left(strInput, Len(strInput)-4)
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

To my understanding this is also much more efficient (and can be made more efficient by defining a range and copying its values to an array).